# Searching through a Binary Tree and returning level of a value

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

I'm attmepting to create a function that searches through a tree for a value and returns the level that the value is at, returning -1 if the value can't be found. To attempt this, I have written the following:

```
tree_search (NODE a t1 t2) x = tree_search_helper (NODE a t1 t2) x 1
tree_search_helper (NODE a t1 t2) x h = tree_search_helper t1 x h
  where
    tree_search_helper (NODE a t1 t2) x h 
      | not (tree_search_helper t1 x h+1 == -1) = tree_search_helper t1 x h+1  
      | (a == x) = h
      | otherwise = tree_search_helper t2 x h+1
    tree_search_helper (LEAF a) x h 
      | (a == x) = h 
      | otherwise = -1
```

However, no matter the input, it returns "1". Can anyone find the issue present!

Comment: `tree_search :: Tree a -> Maybe Int` would be a lot better than a function of type `Tree a -> Int` that returns a magic integer to indicate failure.

Comment: `tree_search_helper t2 x h+1` means `(tree_search_helper t2 x h)+1`. This would have been a type error if you used a `Maybe Int` result.

Answer (score 2):

Defining a function `tree_search_helper` and then defining a local function with the same name using `where` is bound to lead to trouble. Let's consider the problem.

You have a tree type defined as such:

```
data Tree a = LEAF a | NODE a (Tree a) (Tree a) 
  deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
```

You want to find out how deeply located a given value is, or return some value indicating it isn't found. As @chepner indicated in comments, this is a good use for the `Maybe` type, since we will *maybe* find a level.

The simplest case is we look at a leaf and see if it has the value we want. If it is, we return the current level, which we passed in as an argument. Otherwise we return `Nothing` to indicate the value wasn't found.

```
level (LEAF a) v cur_level 
  | a == v    = Just cur_level
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

The other possibility is that we look at a node. If it has the value we're looking for, it's just as easy as the leaf. If it *doesn't* then we have to look in the left or right branches, incrementing the current level by one each time.

Remember that the function returns `Maybe` so we pattern match the result of recursively calling `level` on he left branch to determine if it found the value. If it didn't, we can search the right branch.

```
level (NODE a l r) v cur_level
  | a == v    = Just cur_level
  | otherwise =
      case level l v (cur_level + 1) of
        Just l  -> Just l
        Nothing -> level r v (cur_level + 1)
```

If passing the current level as `0` on the first go each time is annoying, we can hide this.

```
level t v = level' t v 0
  where
    level' (LEAF a) v cur_level
      | a == v    = Just cur_level
      | otherwise = Nothing
    level' (NODE a l r) v cur_level
      | a == v    = Just cur_level
      | otherwise = 
          case level' l v (cur_level + 1) of
            Just l  -> Just l
            Nothing -> level' r v (cur_level + 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

A better return type would be `Maybe Int`, where `Just h` represents a successful search and `Nothing` represents a failed search. This lets you take advantage of the `Monoid` instance of the [`Alt` wrapper](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#g:5) for `Maybe`.

```
tree_search :: Eq a => Tree a -> a -> Maybe Int
tree_search t x = go x 1 t
    where go h (Leaf y) | x == y = Just h
                        | otherwise = Nothing
          go h (Node y l r) | x == y = Just h
                            | otherwise = let rec = go (h+1)
                                          in getAlt (Alt (rec l) <> Alt (rec r))
```

`Alt x <> Alt y`, when used with `Maybe` values, behaves kind of like `or` for Boolean values: `Alt x` if `x` is a `Just` value, `Alt y` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If you make a call with `tree_search_helper t2 x h+1` it will be interpreted as `(tree_search_helper t2 x h) + 1`, so you make a call with the same level, and increment it with one. As a result, the `not (tree_search_helper t1 x h+1 == -1)` will always be true, since the `tree_search_helper t1 x h+1` can never return `-1`.

You thus can rewrite the code to:

```
tree_search_helper :: Eq a => Tree a -> a -> Int -> Int
tree_search_helper (NODE a t1 t2) x h 
  | tree_left != -1 = tree_left
  | a == x = h
  | otherwise = tree_search_helper t2 x (h+1)
  where tree_left = tree_search_helper t1 x (h+1)
tree_search_helper (LEAF a) x h 
  | a == x = h 
  | otherwise = -1
```

and the `tree_search` is just:

```
tree_search :: Eq a => Tree a -> a -> Int
tree_search t x = tree_search_helper t x 1
```

Using `-1` is however not very common in Haskell, usually one returns a `Maybe Int`, and uses `Nothing` in case the item can not be found, so:

```
import Data.Maybe(isJust)

tree_search_helper :: Eq a => Tree a -> a -> Int -> Maybe Int
tree_search_helper (NODE a t1 t2) x h 
  | isJust tree_left = tree_left
  | a == x = Just h
  | otherwise = tree_search_helper t2 x (h+1)
  where tree_left = tree_search_helper t1 x (h+1)
tree_search_helper (LEAF a) x h 
  | a == x = Just h
  | otherwise = Nothing
```